# (JS, PHP, LARAVEL) -> SELECT2 oldValue is null when i try edit and save

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-select2

saya mempunyai kendala saat melakukan edit data namun terdapat beberapa data yang valuenya tidak dapat muncul.
Help me sir, i have problem with form and select2 function, but some data can't showed or null.

this is sreenshot for my app view.[Notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dil7.png)

and this is GET output by request using dev tools [Form Data Staging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8qnV.png).

This is the code in my folder resource>js>app.js

```
`(function ($) {
        $.fn.inputFilter = function (inputFilter) {
            return this.on("input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop", function () {
                if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
                    this.oldValue = this.value;
                    this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
                    this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
                } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
                    this.value = this.oldValue;
                    this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
                }
            });
        };
    }(jQuery));`
```

this is the code in my folder Helper>Form>FormTemplate.php (Function select)

```
`function input_select($name, $label, $array_data, $value, $errors, $col_label = 2, $help = "", array $attributes = array()) {
        $input = '';
    
        // TESTING 30-08-2023
        if (old($name) !== null && old($name) !== "") {
            $value = old($name);
        }

        // BACKUP
        //     if (old($name) != null || old($name) != "") {
        //         $value = old($name);
        //     }
        
    
        $attributes['class'] = @$attributes['class'] . ' m-select2';
        $attributes['placeholder'] = $attributes['placeholder'] ?? 'Select ' . $label;
        $text_attributes = $this->getAttributes($attributes);
    
        $input .= $this->input_base_header($name, $label, $value, $col_label);
        $input .= '<select name="' . $name . '"  id="' . $name . '" ' . $text_attributes . '>';
    
        foreach ($array_data as $key => $value_option) {
            // TESTING 30-08-2023
            $selected = $value === $value_option['id'] ? 'selected' : '';
            // BACKUP
            // $selected = (string) $value == (string) $value_option['id'] ? 'selected' : '';
            $input .= '
            <option  value = "' . $value_option['id'] . '" class = "' . @$value_option['class'] . '" ' . $selected . ' >' . $value_option['text'] . '</option>';
        }
    
        $input .= '</select>';
        $input .= $this->input_base_footer($name, $errors, $col_label, $help);
    
        $allow_clear = $attributes['allow_clear'] ?? 'true';
    
        $this->js[$name] = '
                    $(\'#' . $name . '\').select2({
                        allowClear: ' . $allow_clear . ',
                        placeholder: \'' . $attributes['placeholder'] . '\',
                    });';
    
        return $input;
    }`
```

this is the code in my folder Helper>Form>FormTemplate.php (Function select2)

```
`function input_select2_url($name, $label, $url, $url_api = null, $value, $errors, $col_label = 2, $help = "", array $attributes = array()) {
        $input = '';

        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $value = array();
        }

        if (old($name) !== null || old($name) !== "" || (@$attributes['multiple'] && isset($value[0]) && !isset($value[0]['id']))) {
            //multiple
            $old_value = old($name);
            if (@$attributes['multiple'] && isset($value[0]) && !isset($value[0]['id'])) {
                //if $value is not as expected, it will be searched in the API, the old value will be included in the process from oldvalue, and $value will be emptied
                $old_value = $value;
                $value = array();
            }
            if (!is_array($old_value)) {
                $old_value = array();
                array_push($old_value, old($name)); // TESTING 30-08-2023
                // error_log( print_r($old_value, true) );
            }
            
            foreach ($old_value as $key => $each_old_value) {
                $url_detail = "";
                if ($url_api == null) {
                    $url_for_api = str_replace('admin/', '', $url); //no url api with admin segment in the url
                    $url_explode = explode('/', $url_for_api);
                    //end check data in value
                    $url_detail = $url_explode[1] . '/' . $each_old_value;
                } else {
                    $url_detail = $url_api . '/' . $each_old_value;
                }
                
                //check data in value
                $is_on_array = false;
                foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
                    if (is_array($value2) && array_search($each_old_value, $value2)) {
                        $is_on_array = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                if ($is_on_array) {
                    continue;
                }
                
                $response = General::get_api($url_detail, 'get');
                
                if ($response['meta']['code'] == '200' && $response['meta']['status'] && isset($response['data']['detail']['id'])) {
                    $value[] = array(
                        'id' => $response['data']['detail']['id'],
                        'text' => $response['data']['detail']['name'],
                    );
                } else {
                    //if searching using ?id=
                    $url_detail = substr($url, 1) . '?id=' . $each_old_value;
                    $url_detail = str_replace('/data/select2', '', $url_detail);
                    $response = General::get_api($url_detail, 'get');
                    
                    if ($response['meta']['code'] == '200' && $response['meta']['status'] && isset($response['data']['list'][0])) {
                        $value[] = array(
                            'id' => $response['data']['list'][0]['id'],
                            'text' => $response['data']['list'][0]['name'],
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (old($name) != null || old($name) !== "" || (@$attributes['multiple'] && isset($value[0]) && !isset($value[0]['id']))) {
            //multiple
            $old_value = old($name);
            if (@$attributes['multiple'] && isset($value[0]) && !isset($value[0]['id'])) {
                //jika $value tidak sesuai maka akan di dicari di API, $value yang lama akan ikut prosess nya dari oldvalue dan $value akan di kosongkan
                $old_value = $value;
                $value = array();
            }
            if (!is_array($old_value)) {
                $old_value = array();
                array_push($old_value, old($name)); // TESTING 30-08-2023
                // error_log( print_r($old_value, true) );
            }

            foreach ($old_value as $key => $each_old_value) {

                if ($url_api == null) {
                    $url_for_api = str_replace('admin/', '', $url); //tidak ada url api yang url segment nya admin
                    $url_explode = explode('/', $url_for_api);
                    //end cek data di value
                    $url_detail = $url_explode[1] . '/' . $each_old_value;
                } else {
                    $url_detail = $url_api . '/' . $each_old_value;
                }
                //cek data di value
                $is_on_array = false;
                foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
                    if (is_array($value2) && array_search($each_old_value, $value2)) {
                        $is_on_array = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if ($is_on_array) {
                    continue;
                }
                $response = General::get_api($url_detail, 'get');
                if ($response['meta']['code'] == '200' && $response['meta']['status'] && isset($response['data']['detail']['id'])) {
                    $value[] = array(
                        'id' => $response['data']['detail']['id'],
                        'text' => $response['data']['detail']['name'],
                    );
                } else {
                    //jika pencarian menggukana ?id=
                    $url_detail = substr($url, 1) . '?id=' . $each_old_value;
                    $url_detail = str_replace('/data/select2', '', $url_detail);
                    $response = General::get_api($url_detail, 'get');
                    if ($response['meta']['code'] == '200' && $response['meta']['status'] && isset($response['data']['list'][0])) {
                        $value[] = array(
                            'id' => $response['data']['list'][0]['id'],
                            'text' => $response['data']['list'][0]['name'],
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        $attributes['class'] = @$attributes['class'] . ' m-select2';
        $attributes['placeholder'] = $attributes['placeholder'] ?? 'Select ' . $label;
        $text_attributes = $this->getAttributes($attributes);
        $multiple = $attributes['multiple'] ?? false;
        $input .= $this->input_base_header($name, $label, $value, $col_label);
        $input .= '<select name="' . $name . ($multiple ? '[]' : '') . '"  id="' . $name . '" ' . $text_attributes . '><i class="la la-calendar"></i>';
        foreach ($value as $key => $value_option) {
            $input .= '<option disabled="disabled" value = "' . $value_option['id'] . '"  selected >' . $value_option['text'] . '<i class="la la-calendar"></i></option>';
        }
        
        $input .= '</select>';
        $input .= $this->input_base_footer($name, $errors, $col_label, $help);

        $sort = "";
//        if ($sorting) {
//            $sort = '.select2_sortable()';
//        }
        $allow_clear = $attributes['allow_clear'] ?? 'true';
        $this->js[$name] = ' 
        // select2 id=' . $name . '============

                    $(\'#' . $name . '\').select2({
                        allowClear: ' . $allow_clear . ',
                        placeholder: \'' . $attributes['placeholder'] . '\',
                        ajax: {
                            url: \'' . $url . '\',
                            dataType: \'json\',
                            delay: 250,
                            data: function (params) {
                                return {
                                    query: params.term,';

        if (@$attributes['data-parent']) {
            $data_parent = explode(',', $attributes['data-parent']);
            foreach ($data_parent as $parent) {
                $this->js[$name] .= "\n" . $parent . ': $(\'#' . $parent . '\').val(), ';
            };
        }

        $this->js[$name] .= '
                                };
                   
         },
                            processResults: function (data) {
                                return {
                                    results: data.items
                                };
                            }
                        },
                        //minimumInputLength: 2,
                    })' . $sort . ';';

        if (@$attributes['data-parent']) {
            $data_parent = explode(',', $attributes['data-parent']);
            foreach ($data_parent as $parent) {
                $this->js[$name] .= "
                    $('#$parent').change(function () {
                        $('#$name').val('').trigger('change');
                    });";
            };
        }

        $this->js[$name] .= "
        // end select2 id=$name============  \n";
        return $input;
    }
```

i don't know what happend,this is code running in staging server.
Production server have no problem like this, overall already to use.

My Expected is Vendor and Office show on form data. like this.
my Production code ss [Form data Production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuoTm.png)